Abrir URL directamente desde JavaScript sin usar HTML
En el programa Factory Talk se está creando un SCADA, en el cual se tendrá un botón que abra un archivo local. Actualmente se está abriendo un archivo HTML local el cual tiene un Script que recién abre la URL. ¿Hay manera de que se abra directamente la URL sin necesidad de abrir el archivo HTML? Es decir, que se ejecute el Script sin necesidad de apretar el botón que está en el achivo HTML.

Archivo HTML, es un botón que abre la URL que se va a mostrar.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Informe Electrico</title></head>

<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Informe</button>
    <script src="informe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Archivo JS, donde dimensiono la ventana de la URL que se abrirá.

function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("https://app.powerbi.com", "MsgWindow", 
        "width=1800, height=800, left=50, top=100, menubar=0, resizable=0, titlebar=0", "scrollbars=0", "status=0", "toolbar=0");
    }


Sin usar HTML no creo que sea posible. Sí puedes ejecutar el código sin necesidad de presionar el botón, mientras la página está cargando. Por ejemplo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Informe Electrico</title></head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.open("https://www.google.com")
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Es posible que el navegador bloquee la nueva ventana ya que se abre sin interacción con el usuario. Sin embargo, si no te molesta abrir la página en la misma pestaña puedes usar location.href = "sitio"
